# CSS Grid: Start column at specific x position

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to achieve a CSS grid layout with three columns: Column A and B are always equal to a certain width to let column C start at the same location unless the content in A and/or B becomes too wide.

Or to describe it another way: If A gets bigger, the needed extra width is taken out of B instead of moving both B and C further to the right.

Alternatively, can A and B be placed in the same column but be displayed inline?

I know that this could be achieved by wrapping A and B in another container element, but could it be done using just CSS grid?

```
|<--A-->|<---B--->|<-------C------->|

where:
A + B + C = 100%
A + B = min(30em)
A = min(18em)
```

Comment: No, I don't believe so, There's no facility in CSS-Grid to set a width on TWO combined columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this considering an extra hidden element that you place on both A and B column and you define a `min-width` on it. It's a bit tricky but the idea is that the width of both column will obey to the contraint of A and B and the hidden element.

Here is an example to illustrate the trick. I replaced `30em` by `200px` and `18em` by `50px`

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows:1fr 0;
  height: 30px;
  color:#fff;
  margin:5px;
}

.A {
  background: red;
  min-width:50px;
}

.B {
  background:blue;
}

.C {
  background:green;
}
.container::after {
  content: "";
  grid-column: span 2;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="A"></div>
  <div class="B"></div>
  <div class="C">text here</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="A">some text</div>
  <div class="B"></div>
  <div class="C">text here</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="A"></div>
  <div class="B">some text</div>
  <div class="C">text here</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="A">some text</div>
  <div class="B">some text</div>
  <div class="C">text here</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="A"></div>
  <div class="B">more and more and more text here</div>
  <div class="C">text here</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="A">more and more  text here</div>
  <div class="B">more and more  text here</div>
  <div class="C">text here</div>
</div>
```

The only drawback or probably a simple observation is that the width of A and B will depend on the content of both and the min-width applied on A will make it grow more in case both are empty.

Comment: Apologies if this is the wrong means to contact you -- I couldn't find a way to PM you.  A flexbox question of mine was marked as a duplicate, and I believe that it is more helpful to have it be a standalone question. I'd be happy to discuss more.

Comment: @JS_Riddler you can ping me under your question if you want and I marked you question with a canonical one and marking a question as duplicate isn't a bad thing. You already got your answer and the duplicate cover more than this and you will also find it talking about the bug you are having and a way to solve it.